# Page size increases horizontally as I add a margin-top and margin-left to a div

Tags: html, css

I have created a 3 x 3 column div, using bootstrap, so when I add a margin-left and margin-top to the div, the page size increases horizontally. I want the page size to remain constant while I move the divs.

```css
.col-4 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px 0 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4" id="square_1"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_2"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4" id="square_4"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_5"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4" id="square_7"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_8"></div>
            <div class="col-4" id="square_9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far whatever I have tried with your code the horizontal size is not changing. However, if you can explain a little about what you are trying to achieve where the problem is coming, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's **more proper** way to deal with boxes with **flex system** rather than rows and columns which will provide you **more flexibility** to deal with boxes and **avoid default margins and paddings**, and will **save your container width** in **easy way**.

To **achieve** this **update** your **HTML** code with following

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-4" id="square_1"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_2"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-4" id="square_4"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_5"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-4" id="square_7"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_8"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="square_9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS** with the following code

```
.col-4 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  flex: 0 0 32%;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px 0 0 300px;
}

.container > *{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks man, it works

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer is satisfactory for your inquiry, it would be a very good way to vote useful and accept the answer, thankfully.

Comment: Not enough reputations